# Error occurs when i am saving data from gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Hi I have a grid view for my customers which can have many data (Products)

The problem is that whenever i click save , Error occurs

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
Line 109:cmd.Parameters.Add("@RefNo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = RefNo.Text;
```

Here is the Image of my gridview:

[image]

This is my code(ASP)

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="RefNo" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RefNo" HeaderText="RefNo" InsertVisible="False" 
            ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="RefNo" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="ProductID" 
            SortExpression="ProductID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Quantity" HeaderText="Quantity" 
            SortExpression="Quantity" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" SortExpression="Price" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Amount" HeaderText="Amount" 
            SortExpression="Amount" />
    </Columns>

</asp:GridView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyOwnMeatshopConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT Orders.RefNo, Orders.ProductID, Products.Name, Orders.Quantity, Orders.Price, Orders.Amount FROM Orders INNER JOIN Products ON Orders.ProductID = Products.ProductID">
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" class="btn btn" Text="Save" 
    style="color:White" BackColor="Black" onclick="btnSave_Click"/>
```

This is Code Behind

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace MyOwnMeatshop.User.Orders.SO
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Helper.GetCon());

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                GetUserSO();

            }
        }

        void GetUserSO()
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT SOID, FirstName, LastName, Status, DateOrdered FROM SO";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", Session["userid"].ToString());
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                SOID.Text = dr["SOID"].ToString();
                LbFN.Text = dr["FirstName"].ToString();
                LbLN.Text = dr["LastName"].ToString();
                LbStatus.Text = dr["Status"].ToString();
                LbDateOrdered.Text = dr["DateOrdered"].ToString();

            }
            con.Close();
        }

        decimal GetPrice(int ID) // get price of the selected product
        {
            decimal price = 0;
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Price FROM Products " +
                "WHERE ProductID=@ProductID";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductID", ID);
            price = (decimal)cmd.ExecuteScalar(); // typecasting

            con.Close();
            return price;
        }

        void GetCart()
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Products.ProductID, Products.Name, Orders.RefNo, " +
                "Products.Price, Orders.Quantity, " +
                "Orders.Amount FROM Orders " +
                "INNER JOIN Products ON Orders.ProductID = Products.ProductID " +
                "WHERE Orders.UserID=@UserID AND Orders.Status='In Cart'";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", Session["userid"].ToString());
            //cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Session["userid"].ToString();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            con.Close();
        }

        protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    Label RefNo = row.FindControl("RefNo") as Label;
                    Label ProductID = row.FindControl("ProductID") as Label;
                    Label Name = row.FindControl("Name") as Label;
                    Label Quantity = row.FindControl("Quantity") as Label;
                    Label Price = row.FindControl("Price") as Label;
                    Label Amount = row.FindControl("Amount") as Label;

                    con.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO SODetails (UserID, SOID, RefNo, ProductID, Name, Price, Quantity) VALUES (@UserID, @SOID, @RefNo, @ProductID, @Name, @Price, @Quantity)";

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", Session["userid"].ToString());
                    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SOID", SOID.Text);
                    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RefNo", RefNo);
                    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductID", ProductID);
                    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name);
                    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", Price);
                    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", Quantity);

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SOID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = SOID.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@RefNo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = RefNo.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ProductID.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Name.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Price", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Price.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Quantity", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Quantity.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Amount", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Amount.Text;

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT SOID, RefNo, ProductID, Name, Price, Quantity, Amount FROM MYTABLE";

                    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
                    GridView1.DataBind();

                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @GrantWinney is correct the Gridview row item is not a label use this to get row data.
string RefNo = GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex ].Values[0].ToString();
etc...

Comment: it's bound field. I didn't connect the data by the use of codes i used the gridview task

Comment: @LairdStreak your given code works! it inserted but the values are not same as in the grid view :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are using bound field.You can get value of label in following ways

Getting it using the Data Keys and you can write this code any place where you want.

```
var RefNo= GridView1.DataKeys[rowIndex].Values[0].ToString();
```

Or Getting it by cells:

```
string RefNo= GridView1.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[BoundFieldIndex].Text;
```

Comment: where am i suppose to put it? i'm gonna replace my

    `Label RefNo = row.FindControl("RefNo") as Label;`

to

    `var RefNo= GridView1.DataKeys[rowIndex].Values[0].ToString();` ?

Comment: Yes you should replace your current line of code with  this.You can try this string RefNo= GridView1.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[0].Text; or var RefNo= GridView1.DataKeys[rowIndex].Values[0].ToString(); both should work

Comment: will this work if i'll be saving alot of data into the database?

Comment: how much data size ? it works for any number of rows in gridview

Comment: When i use the two codes you gave its says that RowIndex Does not exist in the current context :( same goes as to the other

Comment: Use this code var RefNo= GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString(); It should works

Comment: Yes it inserted by my name (Product name), price, amount and quantity does not have the right value :(

Comment: but*
The names are numbers too

Comment: if you don't want numbers in names then you should use regular expression validator for it.

Answer (score 0):

This will be easy to handle if you use Template Field s instead of 'Bound Fields'. You can Convert a Bound Field into a Template Field from the Fields dialog box.